# Проблема с пагинацией

Tags: php

Есть код пагинации, код хороший, но есть нюанс, пагинация начинается со второй страницы, т.е. `1 [2] 3 4 5`, это из-за того, что старт отсчёта идёт с 0, а я передаю 1, как ни как первая страница. Всяко пробовал, то с 0 отсчёт идёт, то другой баг

вот код

```
<?php
class SimPageNav
{
    protected $id;
    protected $startChar;
    protected $prevChar;
    protected $nextChar;
    protected $endChar;

    /**
     * Конструктор
     * @param string $id        - атрибут ID элемента <UL> - постраничной навигации
     * @param string $startChar - текст ссылки "В начало"
     * @param string $prevChar  - текст ссылки "Назад"
     * @param string $nextChar  - текст ссылки "Вперед"
     * @param string $endChar   - текст ссылки "В конец"
     */
    public function __construct( /*string*/ $id     = 'pagination pagination-sm', 
                                 /*string*/ $startChar = '&laquo;', 
                                 /*string*/ $prevChar  = '&lsaquo;', 
                                 /*string*/ $nextChar  = '&rsaquo;', 
                                 /*string*/ $endChar   = '&raquo;'  )
    {
      $this->id = $id;
      $this->startChar = $startChar;
      $this->prevChar  = $prevChar;
      $this->nextChar  = $nextChar;
      $this->endChar   = $endChar;
    }   

  /**
   * Получить HTML - код постраничной навигации
   * @param int $all        - Полное кол-во элементов (Материалов в категории) 
   * @param int $limit      - Кол-во элементов на странице
   * @param int $start      - Текущее смещение элементов
   * @param int $linkLimit  - Количество ссылок в состоянии
   * @param string $varName - Имя GET - переменной которая будет использоваться в постр. навигации.
   * @return string
   */
    public function getLinks( /*int*/ $all, /*int*/ $limit, /*int*/ $start, $linkLimit = 10, $varName = 'page' )
    {
      // Нихрена не делаем, если лимит больше или равен кол-ву всех элементов вообще,
      // И если лимит = 0. 0 - будет означать "не разбивать н астраницы".
      if ( $limit >= $all || $limit == 0 ) {
        return NULL;
      }     

      $pages     = 0;       // кол-во страниц в пагинации
      $needChunk = 0;       // индекс нужного в данный момент чанка
      $queryVars = array(); // ассоц. массив полученный из строки запроса
      $pagesArr  = array(); // пременная для промежуточного хранения массива навигации
      $htmlOut   = '';      // HTML - код постраничной навигации
      $link      = NULL;    // формируемая ссылка

      // В этом блоке мы просто строим ссылку - такую же, как та, по которой
      // пришли на данную страницу, но извлекаем из неё нашу GET-переменную:
      $purl = parse_url('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      $pqu = $purl['query'];
      parse_str($pqu, $queryVars); //   &$queryVars

      // Убиваем нашу GET-переменную
      if( isset($queryVars[$varName]) ) {
        unset( $queryVars[$varName] );
      }

      // Формируем такую же ссылку, ведущую на эту же страницу:
      $qe = http_build_query($queryVars);
      $link  = $purl['path'].'?'.$qee;

      //-------------------------------------------------------- 

      $pages = ceil( $all / $limit ); // кол-во страниц

      // Заполняем массив: ключ - это номер страницы, значение - это смещение для БД.
      // Нумерация здесь нужна с единицы. А смещение с шагом = кол-ву материалов на странице.
      for( $i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {
          $pagesArr[$i+1] = $i * $limit;
      }

      // Теперь что бы на странице отображать нужное кол-во ссылок
      // дробим массив со значениями [№ страницы] => "смещение" на 
      // Части (чанки)
      $allPages = array_chunk($pagesArr, $linkLimit, true);

      // Получаем индекс чанка в котором находится нужное смещение.
      // И далее только из него сформируем список ссылок:
      $needChunk = $this->searchPage( $allPages, $start );

      // Формируем ссылки "В начало", "передыдущая" ------------------------------------------------

      if ( $start > 1 ) {
        $htmlOut .= '<li><a href="'.$link.$varName.'=0">'.$this->startChar.'</a></li>'.
                    '<li><a href="'.$link.$varName.'='.($start - $limit).'">'.$this->prevChar.'</a></li>';   
      } else {
        $htmlOut .= '<li class="disabled"><a href="#">'.$this->startChar.'</a></li>'.
                    '<li class="disabled"><a href="#">'.$this->prevChar.'</a></li>'; 
      }
      // Собсно выводим ссылки из нужного чанка
      foreach( $allPages[$needChunk] AS $pageNum => $ofset )  {
        // Делаем текущую страницу не активной:
        if( $ofset == $start  ) {
            $htmlOut .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">'. $pageNum .'</a></li>';            
            continue;
        }        
        $htmlOut .= '<li><a href="'.$link.$varName.'='. $ofset .'">'. $pageNum . '</a></li>';
      }

      // Формируем ссылки "следующая", "в конец" ------------------------------------------------

      if ( ($all - $limit) >  $start) {
        $htmlOut .= '<li><a href="' . $link.$varName . '=' . ( $start + $limit) . '">' . $this->nextChar . '</a></li>'.
                    '<li><a href="' . $link.$varName . '=' . array_pop( array_pop($allPages) ) . '">' . $this->endChar . '</a></li>';            
      } else {
        $htmlOut .= '<li class="disabled"><a href="#">' . $this->nextChar . '</a></li>'.
                    '<li class="disabled"><a href="#">' . $this->endChar . '</a></li>';         
      }         
      return '<div class="text-center mrgp"><ul class="'.$this->id.'">' . $htmlOut . '<ul></div>';
    }

    /**
     * Ищет в каком чанке находится сраница со смещением $needPage
     * @param array $pagesList массив чанков (массивов страниц разбитый по лимиту ссылок на странице)
     * @param int $needPage - смещение
     * @return number Ключ чанка в котором есть нужная страница
     */
    protected function searchPage( array $pagesList, /*int*/$needPage )
    {
        foreach( $pagesList AS $chunk => $pages  ){
            if( in_array($needPage, $pages) ){
                return $chunk;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

Подключаю так:

```
$pageNav = new SimPageNav();
$pages = ceil($co/$num);
echo $pageNav->getLinks($pages, 1, $page, 10, 'page');
```

Comment: кто вам сказал что код хороший?

Comment: Это просто ужас какой-то...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строка 80 заменить на `$pagesArr[$i+1] = $i * $limit+1;`
Строка 95 заменить на  `$htmlOut .= '<li><a href="'.$link.$varName.'=1">'.$this->startChar.'</a></li>'.`

Answer (score 0):

А вести отсчёт с 0, но при выводе показывать число на единицу больше - не?